# How to enable or force files sent to “trash folder” when user deletes any files over FTP client (ubunut18.04 server OS)

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, ftp, trash

We have linux server with OS as "Ubuntu 18.04 Server", we use bitvise ssh client or other ftp client to access our server.

So deleted files should be send to "trash folder" when user deletes it on ftp client.

Any solution how to force the deleted files available in trash folder?

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release, you've tagged your release as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/ESM, but mention 18.04 in the title & description, so which is it? or how do the two relate?  Trash is generally a desktop/GUI thing; server or CLI users are expected to know what they are doing (or the programs involved handle the user-trash features for them where they aren't qualified operators)

Comment: @guiverc release OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS(server OS). Here the files should be moved to Trash folder once user deletes from FTP client(bitvise or Filezila). Is there away to make the option available to move the deleted files to trash folder when it gets deleted over FTP client?